# Why does my Mac .app bundle stop working when I change one file?

Tags: macos, mono, .app

Please excuse me if this question seems too simple but I only have very limited access to a Mac and my knowledge of OSX is relatively limited.

I've written a program using Windows Forms which I now have running under OSX (Yosemite) using Mono.

I would like to make it easily distributable so I've followed [these instructions](https://mhut.ch/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app) which explained how to get it running using an .app bundle. It took me only minutes to get it working. However, now I need to update the .exe file inside the bundle with a newer version.

I therefore opened my working .app bundle and navigated to the MacOS directory. There I replaced the old .exe file with the newest version. When I click on the script (also in MacOS) which calls Mono, Mono runs the .exe as expected. However, it no longer runs from the icon, which just appears briefly in the dock, bounces a couple of times and then disappears.

I've exhausted my knowledge of OSX trying to figure out this problem. I've tried recreating the steps I originally took. I've tried every combination of names and Info.plist. Nothing seems to work.

What's strange is: this happens when I use a working .app bundle and only replace the one .exe file. The whole thing stops working via the icon, even though the script works when I double click on it inside the bundle.

Is there something I'm missing? Some safety feature? Does OSX apply some kind of checksum to bundles? Does it somehow know that it's different to the original bundle I created? I'm utterly lost.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the issue, (that you are failing a signiture check), another potential option is that you are smashing file permissions ( so clearing the executable bit. )

If you disable gatekeeper temporarily you should be able to determine if its a signature failure causing this.

If you have signed your original bundle

A quick additional debug step would be to run from the command line:

```
open /Applications/example.app
```

(replace /Applications/example.app with your app bundle) as so you can get any errors out on stdout/stderr and see them directly.